# Header/navbar/footer elements not importing into new page

Tags: php, header, footer, userfrosting

I'm using UserFrosting and so far I've been able to import all of the default elements into the home page. However, I've now added a second page but nothing happened when I copied the following code from the home page:

```
{% include 'common/components/head.html' %}
     <rest of code>
{% include 'common/components/main-nav.html' %}
     <rest of code>
{% include 'common/components/footer.html' %}   
{% include 'common/components/jumbotron-links.html' %}
```

I then used the following php code:

```
<?php include("../userfrosting/templates/common/components/head.html"); ?>
```

Which seems to work but the page only shows this code found within the head.html file:

```
{% for item in includeCSS(page_group|default("common")) %} {% endfor %} {% for item in includeJSTop(page_group|default("common")) %} {% endfor %}
```

Which obviously is not very useful!

When I keep the home and page2.php file in the same folder (in localhost/userfrosting/templates/common) then I receive Error 404. When I move the file to the default UserFrosting home page directory (which the home.html file isn't actually in) in localhost/public, I get only the above code.

It seems like I'm missing something quite basic here but would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: you should not include head.html but your actual page (page2.php ?)

Comment: wouldn't this import the page that I am in (and trying to import the header/footers into)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing PHP files and template files.  UserFrosting uses a [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) along with the [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) templating engine.  So, you do not need a separate PHP file for each page.  Instead, you should create a new template file for your page:

**userfrosting/templates/common/page2.html**

```
{% include 'common/components/head.html' %}
     // DO NOT use PHP here - just Twig!  See the Twig documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html
{% include 'common/components/main-nav.html' %}
     // More Twig
{% include 'common/components/jumbotron-links.html' %}
{% include 'common/components/footer.html' %}
```

Then you need to link up a URL with this template.  That is done in the **controller**, `public/index.php`, for example like this:

```
// Miscellaneous pages
$app->get('/page2/?', function () use ($app) {    

    $app->render('common/page2.html', [
        'page' => [
            'author' =>         $app->site->author,
            'title' =>          "Page Deuce",
            'description' =>    "This is the second page, aight?",
            'alerts' =>         $app->alerts->getAndClearMessages()
        ]
    ]);          
});
```

I highly recommend going through the tutorial on adding a new page: https://learn.userfrosting.com/building-pages

You can also learn more about MVC, Slim, and Twig here: https://learn.userfrosting.com/basics/overview

Feel free to join in [chat](https://chat.userfrosting.com) if you are still having trouble.